# Paint roller fibers stuck on wall after painting

Tags: drywall, walls, painting, paint

I did spot touch up painting using the following [Home Depot Paint rollers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/9-in-x-3-8-in-High-Density-Polyester-Knit-Paint-Roller-Cover-3-Pack-RS-1433/100090787). I applied two coats of Sherwin William White Shadow flat paint, 20 minutes apart. After that, I got many paint fibers stuck/glued on the wall? Over 50 and counting.

First solution is, buy a much better paint rollers brushes!

Question:

1. Why were the paint bristles falling off such a highly rated, popular Home Depot item?
2. How can this be prevented next time?
3. What is the solution to fix? Get sandpaper, remove and repaint?

**Update:**

I tried sanding with drywall sandpaper, all it does it makes it smoother, but does not remove bristles

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could also be the first coat you did was set up enough to be really sticky yet not fully dry. This could be responsible for pulling so much nap off the roller. Also H/D's better or best quality usually rates last in my book. We will typically apply 1 coat then wait for it to dry completely before adding another coat.

Comment: Was the paint new?  Never had that problem with any rollers from HD

Comment: I haven't personally had that happen (I'm usually buying their purple/"best"), but a guy I work with swears by pulling off the loose stuff on any roller with masking tape.

Comment: 20 mins between coats seems very short. What does the paint can say about re-coat times?

Comment: I have a feeling your comment happened after speaking with my new drywall contractor (he thinks the same)

Comment: btw, I tried sanding with drywall sandpaper, all it does it makes it smoother, but does not remove bristles

Comment: "Your comment happened after…" what do you mean?

Comment: hi @Kyle I have a feeling your comment is correct,  after speaking with my drywall contractor who plans to fix it, he thinks the same

Comment: I routinely use those rollers with excellent results, even with quick recoating. I've never seen fibers in the paint. Could be you got a bad lot.

Comment: You bought the paint from Sherman Williams, should have bought their rollers as well. Would have saved you time and effort.

Comment: btw are the paint bristles left on the wall toxic in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell, exactly, from your picture, but to me it looks more like the 2nd coat pulled little bits of not quite dried paint off the wall leaving white spots behind, instead of leaving bits of the foam roller on the wall. Of course, that's from over here on the other side of the internet, so it's hard to say for certain - maybe it's just lighting.

1. That looks to be about the cheapest roller you can get at the store. You get what you pay for.
2. 20 minutes of drying time between coats is highly unlikely to be enough time for paint to dry.

   - Make sure you're following the directions on the can of paint.
   - Sherwin Williams is generally considered a good brand so it's probably not the paint's fault.

Since you've got a textured wall, a simple fix might just to wait for the paint to thoroughly dry then roll on a new coat. There's a good chance that any extra little bits that may be stuck to the wall will visually disappear once they're the same color as the rest of the wall. Sure, *you* will see them for the first day or two because you know what you're looking for, but give it a few days and you'll probably have a hard time seeing them again.

Sanding will probably leave a smooth spot that will be far more noticeable (when the light hits it at an angle) than a little extra roughness will.

If you find, after a second coat and a couple of days that it's still too obvious for you, you might have to pick the little bits out with some tweezers then paint again.

Oh, also, rollers don't have "bristles" they have "nap". Yours happens to be foam, others have different material. "Bristles" would come off of a brush and could be nylon, horse hair or other material.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, those aren’t foam rollers — they’re knit.

Comment: hi @FreeMan I know they are fibers bristles, because I can actually pull them off my wall, like little strings, they aren't white spots,  unfortunately I should have checked the reviews on that product, it has high rating, but many people are complaining about same issue (about it destroying their whole wall : )

Comment: I also tried repainting a few days later, and its still there, I may have to resand the whole wall and try again, to get a smooth non-shadow finish, its just a small side of the wall

Comment: I bought sandpaper, it doesnt seem to work

Comment: btw are the paint bristles left on the wall toxic in any way?

Comment: I can't imagine they're particularly good for you, @mattsmith5, but "toxic"? Probably not. Are you concerned about breathing them, eating them, what? Maybe you should contact the manufacturer for that particular detail, as I can only imagine that will be difficult for us to answer here and is probably off-topic for [diy.se].

Comment: more like 'breathing' them, do they give off fumes? One of my bed is 2 ft away from the wall, where the paint bristles are stuck cc @FreeMan

Comment: I highly doubt it. Did they give off fumes when you were painting? Again, contact the manufacturer if you're concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies here:

[image]

When you go into the Home Depot store and stand before the wall of rollers, pay careful attention to the labels. They say, *good*, *better*, or *best*. If ones cares at all about the quality of their paint job, and you obviously do, ignore the reviews, which are popularity contests, and pay the few extra dollars for the ones labeled *best*. Or better still, go to Sherman Williams and buy their rollers.

One of those stores caters to painting professionals who care about the quality of their work (and their time) and also sells to anyone walking in the door. The other store with `Home` in the name caters to DIYs whose level of craftsmanship is all over the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use heat gun !

it will soften the paint, so you can try to roll over the defects.

Or use the heat gun to strip that portion of the paint.